# How to create object like angularjs in angular4

Tags: angular, angular5

I am using new angular 4 for learning and created project but I need help how to create object  like anglarjs `$scope.Param = {}; $scope.Param.MyId = "2231dddd";`

How to do this in angular4 and post data into service please check below code

```
export class HomeComponent {
  public forecasts: WeatherForecast[];
  public EntityTypeList: EntityTypeList[];
  public Param: { id: string; };

  CreateDb() {
        this.Param.id = this.selectedValue;
        this.http.post('http://localhost:1101/api/db/CreateDb', this.Param).subscribe(result => {

        }, error => console.error(error));
    }
}
```

Comment: You want dynamic properties to add in `Param`?

Comment: you can directly use public Param = {} and then add property dynamically in it or can create model/interface to define type of object and then use it

Comment: yes i want add properties like this.Param.myname, this.Param.mynumber

Comment: https://nehalist.io/working-with-models-in-angular/

Comment: direct use public Param {};

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can then declare property like this

```
public Param : any = {};
```

Comment: yeah, it can contain any object, array etc.

Comment: can i use this in html page

Comment: <input [(ngModel)]="Param.MyName" />

Comment: like this.. can i use like angularjs

Comment: Yes, you can set into input like you asked in comment.

Answer (score 0):

Or if your param object is a key value pair of string, you can use:

```
public param: {[key: string]: string};
```